# Mule custom connector connection timed out for external web service

Tags: mule, connector

Mule version 3.8

First I created custom connector for local SOAP service and successfully received response using the connector.

Then I created custom connector for remote (internet) SOAP service and got Connection timed out error. I searched Mule docs how to add attributes to custom connector [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-connector-devkit/v/3.8/defining-connector-attributes) and added proxy host and port (already successfully tested using soapUI for the same remote service).

The issue is I'm still getting same Connection timed out error in custom connector. I'm wondering that custom connector is not able to reflect the proxy attributes I specified.

Any advise will be very helpful. Thanks.

Update:

Solved using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550064/apache-cxf-client-proxy-settings) SO thread

Answer (score 0):

```
    HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
    http.getClient().setProxyServer("proxy");
    http.getClient().setProxyServerPort(8080);
    http.getProxyAuthorization().setUserName("user proxy");
    http.getProxyAuthorization().setPassword("password proxy");;
```